# recursion Function return nothing

Tags: c++, function, recursion

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int gcd(int a,int b){

    //while(a!=b)
    {    
    
        if(a>b){
            return gcd(a-b,b);
        }
        else{
            return gcd(a,b-a);
       
        }
    //}    
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    cout<<gcd(9,8);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Hello:
It is gcd finder program but i want to it run without while loop and want to seen what is return but it is not give any thing plz tell me why.
I'm very thankfull of you `your text`

Comment: the code does not compile because the number of `{` doesnt match the `}`s

Comment: after fixing that there is no branch in `gcd` that does not call `gcd` again. its a stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you also miss the base case.
So, your method will cause infinite recursion calls.
It should be

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if(b == 0)
       return a;
    else if(a > b)
       return gcd(a-b, b);
    else
       return gcd(b-a, a);
}
```

But why not use modulo?

```
int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if(b == 0)
       return a;
    else
       return gcd(b, a%b);
}
```